# mysqli_num_rows function returns 1 instead of 0

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fairly new to mysql and php development. I'm trying to understand why the mysqli_num_rows doesn't return what I expect - zero rows when there are definitely no records returned when I run the SQL statement from phpmyadmin.

I've searched around and I have failed to find a specific reason for why this isn't working.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

An extract from my code is shown below:

```
if (isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q'])){

    $sql_wo =   "SELECT MAX(wo_nbr) AS wo_nbr FROM workorders WHERE proj_id = '".$_GET['q']."'";
    $result_wo = mysqli_query($connect,$sql_wo);
    $rowCount_wo = mysqli_num_rows($result_wo);
    echo "$rowCount_wo";
    //returns 1 instead of 0???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `MAX()`, `COUNT()`, etc *you will always get one row returned even if the count or MAX is zero.*

`mysqli_num_rows()` function returns the number of rows in a result set. And when you use `COUNT()` or `MAX()`, there would always be one row giving/showing you the result set.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, Milan. Any suggestion on how I can write the code to return a 0?

Comment: You can fetch the record and check for `wo_nbr`.